# Entity Framework RIA Services How do I include entities within an included entity

Tags: entity-framework, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I have the following hierarchy:

AccountCatagory

```
  AccountType

    AccoungGroup

        GeneralLedger   

            SubsidiaryLedger
```

so each AccountCatagory has AccountTypes, each AccountType has AccountGroups...

Which needs to be loaded in to a tree view:

I need to load everything when the account category is loaded and I wrote it like this:

```
   public IQueryable<AccountCatagory> GetAccountCatagories()
    {
    return this.ObjectContext.AccountCatagories.Include("AccountTypes");
    }
```

Which works fine but only loads AccountTypes. within each AccountCatagory.

Writing an Include on each of the entities GetQuery doesn’t work.

How do I tell RIA services to Include entity when the Included entity also has an include/entity to load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of the way I got mine to work, assuming that all of your foreign keys are set up properly and the proper changes have been made in the metadata file of your Domain Service:

```
return ObjectContext.Users.Include("AccessRole")
    .Include("AccessRole.AccessRoleReports")
```

I have never tried including objects with so many subtypes, but I assume this may work:

```
return this.ObjectContext.AccountCatagories.Include("AccountTypes")
    .Include("AccountTypes.AccountGroups")
    .Include("AccountTypes.AccountGroups.GeneralLedger")
    .Include("AccountTypes.AccountGroups.GeneralLedger.SubsidiaryLedger");
```